# Комментарии из c++/cli (dll) в с#

Tags: c#, c++-cli, комментарии

Как добавить комментарий в C++ CLI, чтобы потом при использовании методов данной dll в c# можно было видеть комментарии к функциям и параметрам?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В .NET для всех языков используется стандартный подход: xml-комментарии, начинающиеся с трёх символов `///`. После компиляции dll будет создан файл xml, содержащий документацию. При наличии этого файла комментарии к методам данной библиотеки будут видны в C# и любом другом языке.

Подробнее смотрите по ссылке [Документация XML (Visual C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177226.aspx).

Чтобы файл документации создавался в процессе компиляции нужно указывать параметр [/doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173501.aspx) компилятора. Смотрите раздел "Установка данного параметра компилятора в среде разработки Visual Studio".

---

Не могу не отметить: хоть там и написано, что переведено вручную, но перевод настолько корявый, что лучше переключаться на английский язык, если вы им владеете. А также могу посоветовать использовать справочные материалы по другим языкам, например [Комментарии к XML-документации (Руководство по программированию на C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b2s063f7.aspx).

Comment: Я ставлю ///, но после компиляции dll файл xml не создается. Может в настройках что то нужно поставить?

Comment: @boksts - Добавил.

Answer (score 0):

В чистом `C++` - никак, вы же через `P/Invoke` вызываете нативные функции. Можно использовать библиотеку на `Managed C++`, и сформировать `.xml` описание функций, которые в ней содержатся.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы в сторону XML-документации смотрел (то есть, в отдельном файле), думаю, получится все необходимое реализовать, но писать этот файл, вероятно, придется, вручную.